# Simple Javascript to change a header image based on Domain name

Tags: javascript, image, dns

I'm struggling here.

I need to change an image in our header based on the domain name that the user entered.

We have 2 domains that point to the same location.  We have a header image map that is called.

```
<img src="header_image.png" border="0" width="1113" height="200" orgWidth="1113" orgHeight="200" usemap="#image-maps-2014-08-15-144022" alt="" />
```

This is the image I need to change.

Just want the header image to be "header_image1.jpg" when user us at www.domain1.com and "header_image2.jpg" to be displayed when at www.domain2.com

It should be simple.  But I'm just lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried doing any logic based on the `window.location.hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem

```js
var url = window.location.host;
if (url == "stackoverflow.com"){
  // Make this visible
  document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
  // Make this invisible
  document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
} else {
  // Make this invisible
  document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
  // Make this visible
  document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```html
<img id="one" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/92/9d/3d/929d3d9f76f406b5ac6020323d2d32dc.jpg">
<img id="two" src="http://renegadehealth.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Cats-Coat.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  We just want to have a different header for each domain.  But all the other content the same.  So if someone enters www.domain1.com then header_image1.png is displayed or if they enter www.domain2.com then header_image2.png is displayed.

Comment: have two headers in the same html code, make one "display:none" in the css, and check the base url with the "window.location.hostname" and use a conditional in javascript to change toggle between the two headers by setting the other to "display:block"

Comment: I have Changed the answer, you can use that code... one is the first header and two is the second one, if the url was not the one mentioned then the second header would be displayed and the first would be hidden

Comment: This looks very promising.  Thank you so much.  I'll let you know how it works

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I had use var url = document.domain instead of var url = window.location.host   Took me a while to figure that one out.  But I finally got it worked out.